# How do I create XML from XSD programatically using C in a Unix environment

Tags: c, xml, linux, unix, xsd

I've searched all over the web including this site but all the answers are related to C++, C# or an existing application. I've written an application in C that can generate XML but the XML is generated based on the elements of a known XSD. I'd like to be able to pass any XSD into the function, parse it, and generate the XML based on the XSD. I'm new to working with XML but not C.

Answer (score 0):

XSD is a schema definition. A schema definition describes the format of a particular XML file.

XSD, by itself, is not a set of instructions to generate any particular file, but merely the rules for what a valid XML file for that schema will contain.

Your question doesn't really mean anything, it's like you're asking the following question:

Here are the formal rules for the grammar and syntax of an English language. I would like a function that takes the grammar and syntax of any language, and then produces a novel that uses that grammar and syntax.

The first thing one might have to specify, in this situation, is what kind of a novel to you want to write. "War and Peace"? "The Chronicles Of Narnia?" "Godfather"?

A particular XSD schema file could, for example, specify an infinite number of potentially valid XML files. An XSD file for the XHTML variant of HTML, if one exists -- I don't know if there is somewhere, but there probably is -- would describe what a valid XHTML document will contain. Every XHTML-compliant document in the world can be described by that particular XSD file. So, let's say that the function you're looking for exists, and you have something like that. So, that means that if your function receives an XSD file to XHTML, you will produce the contents of every XHTML web site on the Internet?

Comment: If my question does not mean anything then why are there responses like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/399921/Generate-Sample-XML-from-XSD

Comment: Why don't you look at what that actually does, and see for yourself.